# Declaration of struct variables in other class when obtained by getters

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, struct

I am using Qt 4.5 so do C++. I have a class like this

```
 class CClass1
    {
         private:
               struct stModelDetails
               {
                      QString name;
                      QString code;
                      ..... // only variables and no functions over here
               };
               QList<stModelDetails> m_ModelDetailsList;        

         public:
               QList<stModelDetails> getModelDetailsList();
               ...               
    };
```

In this I have functions that will populate the `m_ModelDetailsList;`

I have another class say `CClassStructureUsage`, where I will call the `getModelDetailsList()` function. Now my need is that I have to traverse the QList and obtain the `name`, `code` from each of the `stModelDetails`.

Now the problem is even the **CClass1's header file is included** it is not able to identify the type of stModelDetails in `CClassStructureUsage`. When I get the structure list by

```
QList<stModelDetails> ModelList = obj->getModelInformationList();
```

it says `stModelDetails` : **undeclared identifier**.

How I can able to fetch the values from the structure? Am I doing anything wrong over here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've already gotten a couple of suggestions for how to attack your problem directly. I, however, would recommend stepping back for a moment to consider what you're trying to accomplish here. First of all, you've said you only *really* want the `name` member of each `stModelDetails` item. Based on that, I'd start by changing the function to return only that:

```
QList<QString> GetModelDetailNames();
```

or, quite possibly:

```
QVector<QString> GetModelDetailNames();
```

The former has a couple of good points. First, it reduces the amount of data you need to copy. Second, it keeps client code from having to know more implementation details of CClass1. The latter retains those advantages, and adds a few of its own, primarily avoiding the overhead of a linked list in a situation where you haven't pointed to any reason you'd *want* to use a linked list (and such reasons are really fairly unusual).

The alternative to that is to figure out why outside code needs access to that much of CClass1's internal data, and whether it doesn't make sense for CClass1 to provide that service directly instead of outside code needing to access its data.

Comment: No i have to obtain all the values from the struct. I just gave an example in the code. But your second point is a good valid one. I will think of it. But is it a good practice as having only the struct declaration in a header file and including it wherever needed? Take my question as an example for the scenario.

Comment: @liaK:well, if you're going to need the whole struct, it's certainly a good idea to define that struct, yes.

Comment: I'll mark yours as the answer for the approach you told based on the access of data..

Answer (score 4):

Since `struct stModelDetails` is `private`, it is not visible from outside the class. You should declare it in the `public` section of your class instead:

```
class CClass1
{
     private:
           QList<stModelDetails> m_ModelDetailsList;        

     public:
           struct stModelDetails
           {
                  QString name;
                  QString code;
                  ..... // only variables and no functions over here
           };

           QList<stModelDetails> getModelDetailsList();
           ...               
};
```

Comment: @liaK depending on what you want to expose from stModelDetails you might as well make a class out of it and protect private data with accessors

Answer (score 4):

You need to use the fully qualified name `CClass1::stModelDetails`. Now it will tell you it is private :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you declared `stModelDetails` as a private class. Putting it in the public section should fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems:
1. Already mentioned is that you need to move stModelDetails to the public section of your class.
2. Because it is nested, the proper name for it outside of the class is CClass1::stModelDetails.

If you really need access to it from the outside, you may want to consider whether it should be a member of CClass1 or if it should be a stand alone class or struct.  I usually only use nested classes/structs when they are an implementation detail of my class.